# keep div centered to viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form within a container, when the user resizes the window I need to the form to move into the center of the container, and when he goes full screen it should return to the original position.

The problem is the form starts aligned to the right edge of the container. See the screenshot below. As you can see I need a smooth form transition so that it moves along the y when the viewport is resized.

How can i accomplish this solution with either javascript or css?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ns5xxnxs/6/

```
<div id = "slider">
    <div class = "container">
        <div id = "form" class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-8 col-md-3">
        </div>

       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can't understand what you want? You want ease smooth transition or anything else?

Comment: I want the form in the red box to move along the container when the window is resized so that it is never off screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edward** Hi there.
It sound like you are just after a transition to work here when you resize the window. And not centering the form div. because in your fiddle you seem to have that working for  how you want it.

So to get the transition when resized...
You need to have the transition go from one size to another different size.
To do this lets use the col-xx-xx classes to have the transition go from one to the other.

I added in the css a `class` of **transition-with**.

Have a look at the code and for how the container > row > div are used and now where your **slider** `id` is.

Here is the working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf8qty75/)**, just move the inner frame on the left to resize.

(Note)... I use **all** in the `transition: all 2s ease-out;` rather than using `width`, because **all** will animate the div on both sides. If I just used `width` it will only expand from one side. Try both to see what I mean here.

Hope this gets you started.
**CSS**

```
#form{
    height:250px;
    background-color:red;
}
#slider{
    background-color:grey;
}        
.transition-width { 
    transition: all 2s ease-out; 
    webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Transition happens when window resized.</h3>
    <div class="row" id="slider">
        <div id="form" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 transition-width">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--end container-->
```

[image]

Comment: great solution, great answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - https://jsfiddle.net/ns5xxnxs/8/

Bootstrap css was forcing it towards right.
I have changed below thinks to make sure it flows in main container. Changes are below. Hope this helps.

```
#form
{
    height:250px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:0px!important;
    width:100%!important;

}
```

Comment: cool solution but the form is not 100% width it is a fraction of the container maybe 30% or 450 px and sits aligned to the right edge

Comment: If you want #form is to set 30%, and align it in center then this may help - margin-left:35%!important;width:30%!important;